# Is it possible to define two implicits with default values

Tags: scala, implicit

I would like to be able to use a case class something like:

```
case class A[T](item: T)(implicit refine: T => T = (t: T) => t)

A("Hello")
A("World")(_.toLowerCase)
```

Such that I only have to define the refine function when needed.

But my case class also needs a ClassTag and I don't know any way I can also include it. For example the folllowing won't compile:

```
case class A[T](item: T)(implicit refine: T => T = (t: T) => t)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T])
```

Is there a way I can implicitly pass the ClassTag to A as well as the refine function?

Comment: Why do you need `refine` to be _implicit_? Why not just this: `final case class A[T](item: T)(refine: T => T = identity)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T])`?

Comment: I guess that making a parameter of type `T => T` implicit is pointless because for every type `T` implicit of type `T => T` exists in every scope. You can check this: `def test[T] = implicitly[T => T]` compiles. You can just omit this implicit parameter. And default value will never be used.

Comment: Using the implicit syntax allows me to write A("Hello") as opposed to A("Hello)()

Comment: You would have the same syntax with default arguments, e.g. `case class A[T](item: T,  refine: T => T = (t: T) => t)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T])`

Comment: You may find this related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552985/scala-passing-one-implicit-parameter-implicitly-and-the-other-explicitly-is-it

Comment: @Suma It's worth noting that you've changed `equals`, `hashCode` etc. for `A`.